# Transfer to Voicemail only when call not answered, not on rejecting a call (Asterisk)

Tags: asterisk

I am working with Asterisk now and observed call transfers to voicemail even though i have rejected it. 
 Is any way to transfer call to voicemail only when on not answered or not available ?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the default macro-stdexten to deal with the calls? All status options (NOANSWER,BUSY,CHANUNAVAIL,CONGESTION) go to voicemail, you should test which one your reject triggers and just hang up the channel on that type.